# Find best combination in MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, combinations, combinatorics

I need to find best combination using Loop to count "NumerOfSheets" To achieve smallest possible number from among the largest. Taking into account additional blocks to allocate.

My table before running code looks like

```
 ID Oder Quantity Blocks NumberOfSheets
  1  A    350      2      
  2  B    200      1      
  3  C    100      1
```

At the beginning I was using code (I had no additional blocks):

```
Dim recIn As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl1;"
Set recIn = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
While Not recIn.EOF
recIn.Edit
recIn!NumberOfSheets = Round((recIn!Quantity / recIn!Block), 1)
recIn.Update
recIn.MoveNext
Wend
recIn.Close`
```

It worked! But now I have new field in my main form "Forms!frmGlowny!FreeBlocks" Where I keep number of blocks to allocate (additional blocks which I can allocate in the column "Blocks"). This filed is count by another code. What is important now, this is positive integer (usually no more than 20). I need find best way to allocate my free blocks. What is best way?  - The largest number from "NumerOfSheets" should be as small as possible. Suppose that this example Forms!frmGlowny!FreeBlocks = 1 (so it's very simple example). So Let's find where I should allocate my 1 free block (I need do it by hand, because I don't have a code:/).

Combination 1

```
ID Oder Quantity Blocks NumberOfSheets
1  A    350      3       117  
2  B    200      1       200
3  C    100      1       100
```

Combination 2

```
ID Oder Quantity Blocks NumberOfSheets
1  A    350      2       175  
2  B    200      2       100
3  C    100      1       100
```

Combination 3

```
ID Oder Quantity Blocks NumberOfSheets
1  A    350      2       175  
2  B    200      1       200
3  C    100      2       50
```

The smallest possible number from among the largest is in the combination No. 2 (because the largest = 175 so it is smallest from all largest numbers of combinations), so now I know that my 1 free block should be added to B order to column "Block". It's very simple example because I have only A;B;C oders and 1 block to allocate. But When I will have e.g orders: A;B;C:D;E;F;G;H and 14 blocks to allocate count by hand will be terrible:/ Please guys, help me. Any solution what I found on the Internet, is about defined number of rows (orders in my case)
* before running code I always know Order;Quantity;Block(before add additional blocks).

Comment: So basically that's a very long story for this problem: Given a set of orders having quantity Q and blocks B resulting in sheets S = Round(Q/B), how do I distribute n free blocks Bf so that the sum of all sheets is as low as possible?

Comment: No, sum is not important. Only the largest number from "Number Of Sheets" is important. Code should find how to allocate the free bloks to achieve as low as possible " the large number"

Comment: I'm sorry. I do not know how to solve this. I don't think it is a programming question though. It's more a math problem. Maybe you could give it a shot at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @venerik Ok I understand that there's no way to achieve one simple solution. But please tell me, is it possible to write a code which can check every possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add all blocks one at a time. For instance, if you want to add 14 free blocks,  you first add 1. After that you add another one. Repeat adding until all 14 blocks are processed.

I created a [little program](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fmao7yr78ppfb7k/ConsoleApplication1.exe?dl=0) to demonstrate. It is written in C# because I don't have Access at hand. When you start the program with argument 1 it will give you the correct result (add 1 block to order B). When you start it with argument 2, it will show you that it first adds 1 block to order B and then 1 block to order A, leaving the orders like this:

```
 ID Oder Quantity Blocks NumberOfSheets
  1  A    350      3      117 
  2  B    200      2      100
  3  C    100      1      100
```

The source code:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Blocks { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfSheets
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)Math.Round((double)Quantity / Blocks);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var orders = new List<Order> {
            new Order {Id = 1, Name = "A", Quantity = 350, Blocks = 2},
            new Order {Id = 2, Name = "B", Quantity = 200, Blocks = 1},
            new Order {Id = 3, Name = "C", Quantity = 100, Blocks = 1}
        };

        Print(orders, "Initial set");

        // When you start the program you have to provide the number 
        // of free blocks as an argument.
        // Loop through all the blocks to add.
        for (int i = 0; i < Int32.Parse(args[0]); i++)
        {
            var lowestNumberOfSheets = 0;
            var orderToModify = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < orders.Count; j++)
            {
                orders[j].Blocks++;
                // get number of sheets of the order 
                // with the highest number of sheets 
                var highestNumberOfSheets = orders.Max(o => o.NumberOfSheets);
                // when this number is lower than 
                // the lowestnumberofsheets remember order 
                orderToModify = lowestNumberOfSheets == 0 ? j : highestNumberOfSheets < lowestNumberOfSheets ? j : orderToModify;
                // and remember lowestnumberofsheets as well
                lowestNumberOfSheets = lowestNumberOfSheets == 0 ? highestNumberOfSheets : Math.Min(lowestNumberOfSheets, highestNumberOfSheets);
                Print(orders, "Orders after run " + (i + 1) + ", try " + (j + 1));
                orders[j].Blocks--;
            }
            orders[orderToModify].Blocks++;
            Console.WriteLine("Added block to order " + orders[orderToModify].Name);
            Print(orders, "Orders after run " + (i + 1));
        }

    }

    static void Print(List<Order> orders, string message = "")
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) Console.WriteLine(message);

        Console.WriteLine("Id | Name | Quantity | Blocks | Sheets");
        foreach (var order in orders)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" {0} | {1,4} | {2} | {3} | {4} "
                , order.Id
                , order.Name
                , order.Quantity.ToString().PadLeft(8)
                , order.Blocks.ToString().PadLeft(6)
                , order.NumberOfSheets.ToString().PadLeft(6));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

I hope you are able to realize this algorithm in VBA yourself.